# Prépositions: "Il y a une question à/pour moi"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

> Il y a une question pour moi.

Ça veut dire que la question m'est posée. C'est moi qui réponds.

> Il y a une question à moi.

Est-ce que cette phrase signifie la même chose ? Ou est-ce une question que j'ai posé, car 'à moi' est aussi la possession ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Il y a une question à moi

That could be heard from a native french speaker. But is not grammatically correct. Its meaning depends on the context :

> Il y a une question pour moi

You have got the good meaning for that, no need to explain further.

> Il y a une question de moi

Means this is a question i submit

### Il y a une question à :

This construction makes sens, but should be followed by a subordinate clause, such like :

> Il y a une question à laquelle il faut répondre
>   Il y a une question à creuser

The first sentence means that the question has to be answered soon
The second sentence means that the question needs some further research.

> Il y a une question à reformuler

Means the question has to be rephrased.

Comment: « Une question de moi » est peut-être grammaticalement correct mais ce n'est pas dans l'usage. « Une de mes questions » est une formulation bien plus habituelle. « Une question à moi » qui est employé 90% du temps à l'oral (pifomètre mais j'imagine que le vrai chiffre n'est pas si éloigné que ça) et que certains stigmatisent parce qu'on leur a dit que c'est pas académique n'est pas du tout ambigu. Ça ne peut indiquer que l'origine. Au final, vu les fréquences d'utilisation, dire à quelqu'un d'employer « de moi » plutôt que « à moi » c'est parfaitement risible.

Comment: Il n'est pas précisé d'usage oral ou écrit dans l'énoncé du problème, de plus, il n'est pas recommandé d'usage particulier : dire que "Une question à moi" n'est pas grammaticalement correct, c'est autre chose. Que ce soit un usage oral est une autre question, c'est pour ça que j'ai détaillé le sens de "une question à moi". Au final,s'il a un devoir de français à rendre, il a plus de chances avec un "de moi" qu'avec un "à moi". Mais on est bien d'accord que "à moi" sera plus courant à l'oral. De même que plus personne ne prononce le "ne" dans beaucoup de négation, comme par exemple cette phrase

Comment: La question est de savoir si l'on doit tolérer n'importe quelle tendance ou si l'on doit, en vertu d'un savoir personnel plus grand en tant que responsable dans un domaine linguistique et en vertu d'une sensibilité plus grande, donner la préférence au formes que l'on juge avoir une plus grande élégance; pourquoi laisser décider pour tous qui n'a que les plus mauvais moyens de décision? La forme « une de mes questions » est celle à reconnaitre comme étant du meilleur français parce qu'une majorité informée en matière de standard du bien parler le reconnait ainsi; pourquoi le cacher?

Answer (score 1):

Pour comprendre un peu plus la différence, regarder ce que ça donne avec la négation:

> Il y a une question pour moi => Il n'y a aucune question pour moi.
> (Personne ne m'a posé de question)
>
> Il y a une question à moi => Il n'y a aucune question (provenant) de
> moi. (Je n'ai posé aucune question.)

Comment: La première partie est du français que l'on ne peut pas critiquer; la seconde est du français acceptable mais pas du meilleur ; meilleur gout : Il y a une de mes questions. => Il n'y a aucune de mes questions. Je ne vois pas pourquoi on devrait utiliser « de » avec la négation :  « Il n'y a aucune question  à moi. » ne me semble ni plus faux ni plus juste que «  Il n'y a aucune question (provenant) de moi. »

Comment: Ce que je voulais montrer c'est que "à moi" désigne la provenance, la source, la personne qui a posé la question mais apparemment le pari n'est pas réussi.